# How to debug logical errors in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm learning Java and now just looking in to debugging. However, it just came up to my mind and is looking for a solution to how to debug logical errors (maybe what this is called!) in IntelliJ. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int  hour, minute;
        hour = 10;
        minute = 30;

        System.out.println("The total number of minutes is " + 60 * hour + minute);
}
```

As you can see that I made a mistake here, which should be:

```
System.out.println("The total number of minutes is " + (60 * hour + minute));
```

Or

```
System.out.println(60 * hour + minute + " is the total no. of minutes.");
```

But if I have to write bigger programs, then how should I debug this in IntelliJ?

Note:
I edited the question. I got down votes within few minutes along with some useful answers too. Maybe I was not clear with the question, or maybe, Stackoverflow is not for beginners.

Comment: What's to debug? Just hit run and see what errors you get?

Comment: spend some time reading up on intellij's debugging features in their manual - how to use breakpoints, evaluate arbitrary expressions, etc... while it may not help you much with a problem like the one you presented, it's certainly time very well spent for any one who aspires to be a decent programmer. eg: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html

Comment: I googled it before posting here but no where I found how to debug "logical errors". I know if its logical then it's my mistake, but, I was asking that if even it is possible to find it in IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One aspect of the issue is the intermingling of presentation with calculation. As a result, it is difficult to debug the result, as well as to write test cases for it.

Rather than :

```
System.out.println("The total number of minutes is " + 60 * hour + minute);
```

It would likely be preferable to have a method:

```
public int calculateMinutes(int hours, int minutes)
{
   //perform calculations
}
```

Then one could write a series of test cases with known values against the method, and have a reasonable expectation that the result is correct. Then, one
can do something similar to (using the hours, minutes in the OP's question):

```
int totalMinutes = calculateMinutes(hour, minute);
System.out.println("The total number of minutes is " + totalMinutes);
```

In this way, there is a hope of debugging, by both writing test cases and potentially stepping through the method.

TL;DR: separate calculations from presentation to support test cases and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to enclose the calculation in parenthesis so that it's evaluated first:

```
System.out.println("The total number of minutes is " + (60 * hour + minute));
```

Otherwise this expression is interpreted as string concatenation which will lead to an error with the multiplication `*`.

Comment: Thank you, but I did mentioned I did a mistake here and is looking to how to debug this. Maybe I was not clear, so getting down votes!

Comment: @Raju No, not because the question is unclear, but it is not well researched. Using Google you could have easily found ways to debug your program or how to use IntelliJ's builtin debugger. [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging.html), [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/starting-the-debugger-session.html), [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/debugger-basics.html) and [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html) are the very first entries when googling `intellij debugger`. Also there are already answers here on SO.

Comment: I googled it before posting here but no where I found how to debug "logical errors". The above example shows a simple example for which I know the answer, but my question was:

What if I don't know the answer and made a mistake while programming? The answer that will get printed will also be wrong and the whole time I will believe that it's what I was looking for. I hope I was clear. Thanks again.